# R: Extract syntactically similar entries of dataset

Tags: r, extract, similarity

I have a sizeable data set that includes several hundred company names and looks something like this:

```
Name:
Earth Ltd.
Rocket International LLC
Space Corp LLC
Space Corporation LLc
Space International Corporation Ltd
Satellite Global
```

Some entries are just different spellings (sometimes misspellings or renaimings) or (for my purposes) the same company. I am trying to collapse these different spellings into one consistent version, e.g. `Space Corp LLC, Space Corporation LLc, Space International Corporation Ltd` into  `Space Corp. LLC`.

Is there a script or package that lets me extract syntactically or otherwise similar entries, so I can see which entries I need to collapse?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
corp <- c( 'Earth Ltd.', 'Rocket International LLC', 'Space Corp LLC', 'Space Corporation LLc', 'Space International Corporation Ltd', 'Satellite Global')
corp <- data.frame(name = corp)
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
corp
                                 name
1                          Earth Ltd.
2            Rocket International LLC
3                      Space Corp LLC
4               Space Corporation LLc
5 Space International Corporation Ltd
6                    Satellite Global
 
corp %>% mutate(newcol = str_replace_all(name, 'Space Corp LLC|Space Corporation LLc|Space International Corporation Ltd', 'Space Corp. LLC'))
                                 name                   newcol
1                          Earth Ltd.               Earth Ltd.
2            Rocket International LLC Rocket International LLC
3                      Space Corp LLC          Space Corp. LLC
4               Space Corporation LLc          Space Corp. LLC
5 Space International Corporation Ltd          Space Corp. LLC
6                    Satellite Global         Satellite Global
>
```